# Finding the Green Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, greens-function

I'm having some trouble finding the Green function of the following differential equation:
$$
\frac{d[x y'(x)]}{dx} = f(x)\\
0 \leq x \leq 1\\ 
y(1) = 0
$$
$y(0)$ is finite.

Comment: What kind of trouble? Could you please add more context?

Comment: I can't solve it

Comment: Why? Are you not familiar with the method itself? Or is there something in this equation that makes it hard to apply? If you want to get a useful answer, please ask a question with more context. Unless you just want someone to solve the problem for you?

Comment: Set $f\equiv 0$ and find solutions for $0\le x\le x'$and $x'\le x\le1$.

Comment: Hi, I've been trying to find the homogeneous solutions and then move to a non-homogeneous one, using the method of parameter variations, but still, my answer is not correct. I don't know if I'm using the wrong method or making silly mistakes. Still, I'd appreciate if someone could solve it, so I can see where I'm getting it wrong.

Comment: For $0\le x\le x'$, $g(x,x')=\log(x')$.  For $x'\le x\le 1$, $g(x,x')=\log(x)$.